# How to animate ListBoxItem position

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox, storyboard

I am having some trouble animating the items in my ListBox. Animations on the OpacityProperty work great but when i try to animate the position of my ListBoxItem it simply does not move an inch (No exceptions are thrown, not even a log message indicating error).

Here is the code i am using:

```
private void deletAnimation()
    {
        Todo todoToDelete = App.ViewModel.Todos[1];

        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

        DoubleAnimation alphaAnim = new DoubleAnimation();
        alphaAnim.From = 1;
        alphaAnim.To = 0;
        alphaAnim.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
        ListBoxItem target = TodoList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(todoToDelete) as ListBoxItem;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(alphaAnim, target);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(alphaAnim, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));

        storyboard.Children.Add(alphaAnim);

        for (int i = App.ViewModel.Todos.IndexOf(todoToDelete) + 1; i < App.ViewModel.Todos.Count; i++)
        {
            Todo todo = App.ViewModel.Todos[i];
            target = TodoList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(todo) as ListBoxItem;

            DoubleAnimation translateAnim = new DoubleAnimation();
            translateAnim.From = target.RenderTransformOrigin.Y;
            translateAnim.To = target.RenderTransformOrigin.Y - target.ActualHeight;
            translateAnim.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
            translateAnim.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);

            Storyboard.SetTarget(translateAnim, target);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translateAnim, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.YProperty));

            storyboard.Children.Add(translateAnim);
        }

        storyboard.Begin();
    }
```

Some things i have noticed while debugging:

1. The RenderTransformOrigin.Y property is always 0 no matter which ListBoxItem is referenced.
2. The Height property is NaN though the ActualHeight property is 67
3. The parent property of the ListBoxItem is null

These two things make me wonder if i am given a reference to a ListBoxItem that is not rendered of the screen? But as the Opacity animation works perfectly and all of my list is visible(only contains 3 items at the moment) i do not see how this could be the case.

I have also tried using a PointAnimation and animating the RenderTransformOrigin property directly but this gave the same result (nothing that is).

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What effect are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: When deleting an item in the list that item will fade out and all items under it will slide up.

Comment: Can it be in xaml? Unfortunately I can only think of how to do it with xaml with a storyboard and FluidMoveBehavior to provide the effect you're after.

Comment: xaml is fine, i just prefer c# as i feel it is easier to reuse and i have never used xaml storyboards before ;)

Comment: Would greatly appreciate a short sample of how to do this as i have never done animations with xaml before :), and put it in an answer so i can accept it as well ;)

Comment: Well apparently its a bit different for WP7 from just using the layout states like in a plain Silverlight. So while looking for a workaround I found this, and ArtefactAnimator sounds like a good workaround.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269890/wp7-animating-add-remove-item-in-a-listbox give it a shot, if not I'll try to whip out something before bed. Cheers!

Comment: after a bit of a struggle i actually got FluidMoveBehavior to work!:) it look excellent for reordering of the list. deleting from the list howing does not provide a satisfying animation, and i have yet to figure out how to provide my own details of how the animation should act.. code i used was from second answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237563/wp7-listbox-how-to-allow-user-to-order-items

Comment: Ya there's wherein I got confused, you would have to have a way to update the order on delete function to trigger any animation properties, unfortunately I'm not a c# guy but if you keep it in xaml could prob figure something out if you can just replay your storyboard to update the list when an item is deleted? Which I assume is where GestureListener comes in handy?

Comment: I really don't know. But as i said, all the animations work. i would just like to state my own animations now as the delete animation is horrific :/ i tried animating the deleting item from c# and then collapsing the view to not show the xaml animation on that view but the xaml animation seemed bring back the listboxitem into view again -.-

Comment: Is it something you can make as a State in the VisualStateManager and call on delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out this link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasongin/archive/2011/01/03/wp7-reorderlistbox-improvements-rearrange-animations-and-more.aspx

Someone has created a class that you can easily incorporate into your app. This has animations for adding/removing items from your list.

This should save you a lot of time and frustration.